# Parameters nginx rewrite request regular expressions

Tags: nginx, proxy, location, reverse-proxy, pcre

Server Number 1 receives the request like `http://server111.com/box_example/?boo=test&too=best` and proxies rewrite request like `http://server222.com/u=box_example&?boo=test&too=best` to the server number 2

I try here are the options:

```
location ~*/ {
   rewrite  ^/([a-z0-9])$   u=box_example&?boo=test&too=best break;
   rewrite  ^/(~*[a-z0-9])$ u=box_example&?boo=test&too=best break;
...
proxy_pass         http://192.168.200.9:3000;
```

Please tell me how.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
location / {
    rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /?u=$1&$args break;
    ...
    proxy_pass         http://192.168.200.9:3000;
```